# Host config bot framework [supportsInteractivity]

Tags: json, node.js, config, botframework, host

I am working on the webchat bot framework, more particularly on the hostconfig part of the adaptive card.
I want to use container selectaction but I do not have the expected display. 
I created a basic card with container that I display on my chatbot but when I put the mouse cursor on the container, the card does not make the interactive effect yet the property supportsInteractivity is true.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thans you

Here is my hostconfig:

```
{
  "supportsInteractivity": true,
  "spacing": {
    "small": 4,
    "default": 8,
    "medium": 16,
    "large": 24,
    "extraLarge": 32,
    "padding": 8
  },
  "separator": {
    "lineThickness": 1,
    "lineColor": "#cccccc"
  },
  "fontFamily": "\"Segoe UI\", sans-serif",
  "fontSizes": {
    "small": 12,
    "default": 13,
    "medium": 15,
    "large": 17,
    "extraLarge": 19
  },
  "fontWeights": {
    "lighter": 200,
    "default": 400,
    "bolder": 700
  },
  "containerStyles": {
    "default": {
      "backgroundColor": "#00000000",
      "foregroundColors": {
        "default": {
          "default": "#000000",
          "subtle": "#808c95"
        },
        "accent": {
          "default": "#2e89fc",
          "subtle": "#802E8901"
        },
        "attention": {
          "default": "#ffd800",
          "subtle": "#CCFFD800"
        },
        "good": {
          "default": "#00ff00",
          "subtle": "#CC00FF00"
        },
        "warning": {
          "default": "#ff0000",
          "subtle": "#CCFF0000"
        }
      }
    },
    "emphasis": {
      "backgroundColor": "#08000000",
      "foregroundColors": {
        "default": {
          "default": "#333333",
          "subtle": "#EE333333"
        },
        "accent": {
          "default": "#2e89fc",
          "subtle": "#882E89FC"
        },
        "attention": {
          "default": "#cc3300",
          "subtle": "#DDCC3300"
        },
        "good": {
          "default": "#54a254",
          "subtle": "#DD54A254"
        },
        "warning": {
          "default": "#e69500",
          "subtle": "#DDE69500"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "imageSizes": {
    "small": 40,
    "medium": 80,
    "large": 160
  },
  "actions": {
    "maxActions": 100,
    "spacing": "default",
    "buttonSpacing": 8,
    "showCard": {
      "actionMode": "inline",
      "inlineTopMargin": 8
    },
    "actionsOrientation": "vertical",
    "actionAlignment": "stretch"
  },
  "adaptiveCard": {
    "allowCustomStyle": false
  },
  "imageSet": {
    "imageSize": "medium",
    "maxImageHeight": 100
  },
  "factSet": {
    "title": {
      "color": "default",
      "size": "default",
      "isSubtle": false,
      "weight": "bolder",
      "wrap": true,
      "maxWidth": 150
    },
    "value": {
      "color": "default",
      "size": "default",
      "isSubtle": false,
      "weight": "default",
      "wrap": true
    },
    "spacing": 8
  }
}
```

and there is my card :

```
    {
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Text",
                    "weight": "bolder",
                    "size": "large",
                    "color": "accent",
                    "horizontalAlignment": "center"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "separator": true,
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "text",
                    "size": "medium",
                    "horizontalAlignment": "center",
                    "wrap": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "separator": true,
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "text",
                    "horizontalAlignment": "center"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "style": "default",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Container",
                            "style": "emphasis",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "text"
                                }
                            ],
                            "selectAction": {
                                "type": "Action.Submit",
                                "title": "text",
                                "data": {
                                    "action": "1"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Container",
            "separator": false,
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "text",
                    "horizontalAlignment": "center"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "style": "default",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Container",
                            "style": "emphasis",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "text"
                                }
                            ],
                            "selectAction": {
                                "type": "Action.Submit",
                                "title": "text",
                                "data": {
                                    "action": "1"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "style": "default",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Container",
                            "style": "emphasis",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "TextBlock",
                                    "text": "text"
                                }
                            ],
                            "selectAction": {
                                "type": "Action.Submit",
                                "title": "text",
                                "data": {
                                    "action": "1"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "",
            "data": {
                "action": "2"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Action.ShowCard",
            "title": "",
            "card": {
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "Input.Text",
                        "id": "comment",
                        "isMultiline": true,
                        "placeholder": "Add a comment"
                    }
                ],
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "type": "Action.Submit",
                        "title": "Soumettre",
                        "data": {
                            "action": "3"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Rate, could you share the code you've tried in your post? Could you also indicate what version of webchat (npm, cdn, iframe, etc) and what version of Adaptive Cards you're using? Just to verify, you are using a v3 node bot, correct?

Comment: Hello, yes I using v3 node bot and I use the V1.0 of adaptive cards.

Comment: Hi Rate, sorry I just saw your hostconfig code! Could you add your adaptive card as well?

Comment: I edited my message with the adaptive card code

Comment: Can you specify which interactive effect is missing with regard to your card? I have tried out the code on the [adaptive card visualizer](https://adaptivecards.io/visualizer/index.html?hostApp=Bot%20Framework%20WebChat) but it appears to be in working order, as the interactive elements are correctly working there. Could you post the way you import webchat in your application?